# Authorize.net - How to increase "Product Name Maximum character limit"?

Tags: authorize.net

I have integrated Authorize.net, but i got the error message "Line item 1 is invalid", then i understood the reason, product name maximum character limit is 31, when submit with short product name it works fine..., but how to increase this "Product Name Maximum character limit"

Please anyone help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's called a "limit" because that's the maximum number of characters you can use no matter what. You can't increase it. If you have products with very long names you should increase an abbreviation that meets the 31 character limit.